# Adjusting layout in minipage within tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

What I want to achieve are nodes in which I can put a small index in the top left with either a one or two line description in the center. The nodes should all have the same size. What I achieved with inspiration from [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements/) is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}

\tikzstyle{WorkPackage} = [
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black,
    very thick,
    minimum width = 12em,
    minimum height=4.1em, 
    text width=10em,    
    node distance=0.5cm]

\newcommand{\CommonElementTextFormat}[2]
{
\begin{minipage}{10em}
\begin{spacing}{0.1}
    \centering
    {\hspace{-10.5em} \footnotesize #1 \hfill}%
    \linebreak
    {#2}
    \linebreak
    {\footnotesize \vspace{.6em}}
\end{spacing}
\end{minipage}
}
```

When I now create two nodes, one with single line, and one with a multi-line description the index is messed up:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[WorkPackage] {\CommonElementTextFormat{1)}{Image Acquisition \& Camera Calibration}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[WorkPackage] {\CommonElementTextFormat{1)}{Image Acquisition}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

edit: The reduced spacing I chose because otherwise a single lined description within the huge node seemed kinda lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}

\tikzstyle{WorkPackage} = [
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    draw=black,
    very thick,
%    minimum width = 12em,
%    minimum height=4.1em, 
%    text width=10em,    
    node distance=0.5cm]

% \parbox allows you to specify the height as well as the width
% Placing a 1em margin or both sides of the parbox gives the
% left shifted index somewhere to go.

\newcommand{\CommonElementTextFormat}[2]% #1=index, #2=text
{\raisebox{16pt}{\makebox[1em][l]{\footnotesize #1}}%
\parbox[c][4em]{10em}{\footnotesize%
 \vfil\centering{#2}\vfil
}\hspace*{1em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[WorkPackage] {\CommonElementTextFormat{1)}{Image Acquisition \& Camera Calibration}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[WorkPackage] {\CommonElementTextFormat{1)}{Image Acquisition}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[WorkPackage] {\CommonElementTextFormat{1)}{A three line footnote that goes on and on and on and on}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[WorkPackage] {\CommonElementTextFormat{1)}{A four line footnote that goes on and on
 and on and on and on and on and on and on}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: footnotes]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I additionally included a `\setstretch{0.1}` to be able to use `\normalsize` for the description and added both `\newcommand{\WorkPackageElement}[2]{\CommonElementTextFormat{#1)}{#2}}` and
`\newcommand{\ActionElement}[1]{\CommonElementTextFormat{\medskip}{{#1}}}` to be able to create nodes without an index and not messing up the description

Comment: I have a better solution now which can handle 3 anf 4 line footnotes.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use TikZ for the placement of that number.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,setspace}
\tikzset{WorkPackage/.style={
  shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, very thick, text width=+10em,
  align=center, inner xsep=+1em, minimum height=+4.1em, font=\setstretch{.1},
  append after command={
    \pgfextra{\footnotesize} node[anchor=north west] at (\tikzlastnode.north west) {#1}}}}
\newcommand*\WorkPackage[3][]{\tikz[#1]\node[WorkPackage={#2}]{#3};}
\begin{document}
\WorkPackage{1)}{Image Acquisition \& Camera Calibration}
\WorkPackage{2)}{Image Acquisition}

\WorkPackage{3)}{A three line footnote that goes on and on and on and on}
\WorkPackage{4)}
  {A four line footnote that goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]